# Sorting an array of struct pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a function to sort an array of struct pointers alphabetically like so:

```
 void insertionSortAlpha(candidate* person[], int lo, int hi) { 
        candidate* insertItem;
        insertItem = malloc(sizeof(candidate));
        insertItem->name = malloc(25*sizeof(char));
        insertItem->numVotes=malloc(sizeof(int));   

        int i;
        for(i=lo+1; i<=hi; i++) { 
            insertItem = person[i];
            int k = i - 1;
            while (k > 0 && strcmp(insertItem->name, person[k]->name) < 0) { 
                person[k + 1] = person[k];
                --k;
            }
            person[k + 1] = insertItem;
        }
    free(insertItem->numVotes);
    free(insertItem->name);
    free(insertItem);}
```

I then call the function and free the memory like so. The names are populated from a file. When printing out, it always skips the name and number for the third element in the array. It also gives me an invalid pointer error. Why is this happening?

```
insertionSortAlpha(Person, 0, 9);
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("Sorted Alphabetically\n");
  for (i=0; i<10;i++) {
    printf("%s =  %d votes \n", Person[i]->name, *Person[i]->numVotes);
  }
 for (i =0; i<10; i++) { 
    free(Person[i]->numVotes);
    free(Person[i]->name);
    free(Person[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Your assignment to `insertItem` in the loop leaks the memory allocated before the loop.  I don't think you need the memory allocation or release at all in the sort function.  In fact, I'm sure you don't; you free the last item that was stored in `insertItem` after the loop, which then gives you problems later when you access (and free) already freed memory.

Comment: What does your file look like btw?

Answer (score 2):

There was a bit more work than there should be to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but this code basically validates my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500072/sorting-an-array-of-struct-pointers#comment68243969_40500072):

> Your assignment to `insertItem` in the loop leaks the memory allocated before the loop. I don't think you need the memory allocation or release at all in the sort function. In fact, I'm sure you don't; you free the last item that was stored in `insertItem` after the loop, which then gives you problems later when you access (and free) already freed memory.

Your data structure with the allocated single integer is wasteful (especially on a 64-bit machine); it should be a plain `int` member of the structure.  If you're going to deal with fixed size names, you could make the name into a fixed size array too.  However, that's a minor refinement (and not implemented).  The integer pointer made it inconvenient to use the `candidate` structure for the internal data.  I could have used C99 'compound literals' such as `&(int){ 8000 }`, but that requires more explanation (and the array can no longer be `static`, and the call to `new_candidate()` has to be modified).

You also needed to change the limit in the `while` loop from `k > 0` to `k >= 0`; otherwise, Henrietta stays at the front of the list.

Here is a more-or-less minimal MCVE with the fixes in place:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct candidate
{
    char *name;
    int  *numVotes;
} candidate;

static
void insertionSortAlpha(candidate *person[], int lo, int hi)
{
    candidate *insertItem;
    //insertItem = malloc(sizeof(candidate));
    //insertItem->name = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    //insertItem->numVotes = malloc(sizeof(int));

    int i;
    for (i = lo + 1; i <= hi; i++)
    {
        insertItem = person[i];
        int k = i - 1;
        // k > 0 --> k >= 0
        while (k >= 0 && strcmp(insertItem->name, person[k]->name) < 0)
        {
            person[k + 1] = person[k];
            --k;
        }
        person[k + 1] = insertItem;
    }
    //free(insertItem->numVotes);
    //free(insertItem->name);
    //free(insertItem);
}

typedef struct BaseData
{
    char *name;
    int   numVotes;
} BaseData;

static void *emalloc(size_t size, const char *func)
{
    void *vp = malloc(size);
    if (vp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory in %s()\n", size, func);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return vp;
}

static candidate *new_candidate(const char *name, int votes)
{
    candidate *person = emalloc(sizeof(*person), __func__);
    person->name = emalloc(25, __func__);
    assert(strlen(name) < 25);
    strcpy(person->name, name);
    person->numVotes = emalloc(sizeof(int), __func__);
    *person->numVotes = votes;
    return person;
}

int main(void)
{
    candidate *Person[10];
    static const BaseData people[] =
    {
        { "Henrietta",  8000 },
        { "Eric",       5000 },
        { "Beatrice",   2000 },
        { "Diana",      4000 },
        { "Francesca",  6000 },
        { "George",     7000 },
        { "Ian",        9000 },
        { "Janice",    10000 },
        { "Adrian",     1000 },
        { "Charles",    3000 },
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Person[i] = new_candidate(people[i].name, people[i].numVotes);

    insertionSortAlpha(Person, 0, 9);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Sorted Alphabetically\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%-15s = %6d votes\n", Person[i]->name, *Person[i]->numVotes);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        free(Person[i]->numVotes);
        free(Person[i]->name);
        free(Person[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Sorted Alphabetically
Adrian          =   1000 votes
Beatrice        =   2000 votes
Charles         =   3000 votes
Diana           =   4000 votes
Eric            =   5000 votes
Francesca       =   6000 votes
George          =   7000 votes
Henrietta       =   8000 votes
Ian             =   9000 votes
Janice          =  10000 votes
```

Congratulations to Janice for winning the election.